# need some clarification about DAG (Directed Acyclic Graph)

Tags: graph-algorithm, directed-acyclic-graphs

I know the definition of a DAG, which is a directed graph without any cycle. My question is: Can I consider 2 separate DAGs as one DAG? If not, what is the technical name for a set of DAGs?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A DAG can have disconnected parts, since the only requirements are being a directed, acyclic graph.

If you want to specify that it is connected, you could say "connected DAG".